# Image aspect ratio change after inserting it into imageview

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiimageview

So I'm trying to load an image from camera into image view. I've got it done, but images aspect ratio changes.

I tried setting content mode for imageview but no effect.
Here is how i do it:

```
UIImage *picture=[UIImage imageWithData:slika];
    imageview = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    [imageview setImage:picture forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is image view your own view? Or it's, for example, cell's default imageView?

And you should write so:

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:picture];
```

or

```
[imageView setImage:picture];
```

There is no method `[imageview setImage:picture forState:UIControlStateNormal];` for UIImageView, it only available for UIButton (and may be for some other UIControls, but UIImageView not subclass of UIControl - it direct subclass of UIView) . But button does not scale images preserving aspect ratio.

Comment: Why don't you have a `UIImageView` with your image, and on top of that position a `UIButton` with type `Custom` and no text. That way you can retain the aspect ratio of your image, but still have a control on it.

Comment: That's exactly what i did, after i realized where is the problem :D